# jquery/javascript prepend text into input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, placeholder

I have an input box using an html5 placeholder:

```
<input type="text" name="website" class="url" required placeholder="enter website">
```

Using jQuery or straight javascript, I wanted to prepend a string to the data being typed by the user on focus. If the field contains more data than the preset string variable (ex: http://example.com) then the field satisfies my requirements. If it only contains the original string ('http://') then clear the input value and display the placeholder.

The following code works for me.

```
var input = $("#processor .url");
var prefix = 'http://';

input.focus(function() {
    if (input.val().indexOf(prefix) == -1) {
        input.val(prefix + input.val());
    }
}).blur(function() {
    if (input.val() == prefix) {
        input.val('');
    }
});
```

Is there a better way to write this for performance, etc..., is my real question?

Comment: you want to prepend "http://" to user input?

Answer (score -1):

This is easier than it looks actually.
I made a demo based on @Tahir Yasin's comment.

css:

```
.grey { color:#aaa; }
```

html:

```
<input type="text" />
```

jQuery:

```
var inputval = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Define your default value to show on input
    $("input[type='text']").val("Enter your link here...");
    // Add grey color or optionally blur effect
    $("input[type='text']").addClass('grey');
    // Save your default value
    inputval = $("input[type='text']").val();
    $("input[type='text']").focusin(function() {
    // if textbox is empty or got the default value
    if ($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == inputval) {
        // Clear the box
        $(this).val("http://"); // Your text here..
        // Remove grey color
        $(this).removeClass('grey'); }
    }).focusout(function() {
        // if textbox is empty or just contains your value
        if ($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == "http://" ) {
            // Put your Default value back
            $(this).val(inputval);
            // Add grey color
            $(this).addClass('grey'); }
    });
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/TgZ8L/

I just like using jQuery on everystep of the action. But as you can see my code less performent than yours so you are already using the most performent way.

here is the demo based on your code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/qbLyD/

you can see the difference by yourself its nearly the same but obviously your code is faster.